# Setting bounds based on layer size

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

I am using GeoServer+OpenLayers and I have a base layer (Google map) and some additional layers (OpenLayers.Layer.WMS); users can show or hide these layers.
I would like when user show a layer then the map should zoom to the area where layer has data.

I know I have to use map.zoomToExtent(bounds) but I don't know how get this information from the layer.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Use a WMS GetCapabilities request to find the bounds of any layer in a WMS